# Does there exist a prime $p$ satisfy this inequality :$(\frac{\pi}{p})^n<p<(\frac{2\pi}{p})^n$ for all $n>1$?

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers

I'm interesting always for the prime distribution , I want to find such prime $p$ satifying the following inequality for all integers $n >1$:

$(\frac{\pi}{p})^n<p<(\frac{2\pi}{p})^n$ ? I have tried $p=3$,The inequality failed for $n=25$ , Any prime ?

Comment: Does this make sense?  For $p≥7$ we have $\frac {2\pi}p<1$ so....

Answer (score 1):

We can immediately see that the inequality must fail for $p\ge7$, since the right-hand side will then be less than or equal to $1$. $p=3$ and $p=5$ fail at $n=1$, so it remains to check $p=2$, but that fails for $n=2$, so no such $p$ exists.